# Extrair emails de um Memo

Tags: delphi, email, memo

Tenho um componente `memo`, dentro dele existe um texto grande, e nesse texto contém vários endereços de e-mails espalhados.

Como posso fazer para extrair somente os e-mails desse `memo1` e jogar no `memo2`?

Comment: Coloque parte do texto que está no memo1, eles estão separados por algum padrão?

Comment: @rray, não sem padrão, é um texto grande e dentro dele existem espalhados diversos endereços de e-mail da seguinte forma: exemplo@exemplo.com.br, ou exemplo@exemplo.com. Preciso criar uma forma de rastrear esse memo e capturar somente as contas e colocar no outro memo, estou tentando usar expressões regulares pois é mais ´rapida né, mais não estou conseguindo!

Comment: Pelo menos estão separados por espaço?

Comment: @rray, mais ou menos assim amigo: exemplo@exemplo.com.br 32l32k323l2323232322222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 exemplo@exemplo2.com

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o exemplo que deixou no comentário dá a entender que os emails estão separados por espaços entre o texto, bastou então procurar linha a linha por os espaços em branco a cada palavra que encontra passamos para uma variável e verificamos se a palavra pode corresponder a um email, se sim então guardamos, e seguimos para a próxima palavra.

Para testar, precisa de criar um novo projeto, adicionar ao projeto 1 botão, 2 memos e copia o código:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //escreve texto no memo
  Memo1.Text := 'exemplo@exemplo.com.br 32l32k323l23232@2222222  2.2.22 exemplo@exemplo2.com 3434534 dsf s32234324 xxxtttaaa@gmail.com  adas asdfaaaaaaaaaaaa xpto@hotmail.com';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i, APos: Integer;
    ALine, AWord, ALetter, AEmail: String;
    FoundAT, FoundDOT: boolean;
begin
  //vai correr as linhas todas do memo
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    Begin
      ALine := Memo1.Lines[i];

      //enquanto a linha tiver texto verifica
      While ALine <> '' do
        Begin
          FoundAT := False;
          FoundDOT := False;
          AEmail := '';

          //procuro espaços o próximo espaço " " 
          APos := Pos(' ', ALine);
          if (APos > 0) then
            begin
              //pego a palavra e apago-a da variável ALine
              AWord := Trim(AnsiMidStr(ALine, 1, APos - 1));
              Delete(ALine, 1, APos);
            end
          else
            Begin
              //quando não encontramos mais " " então pegamos o resto da linha  
              AWord := ALine;
              ALine := '';
            End;

          AEmail := AWord;

          //vamos analisar letra a letra 
          while AWord <> '' do
            Begin
              ALetter := Trim(AnsiMidStr(AWord, 1, 2 - 1));
              Delete(AWord, 1, 1);

              //procuramos pelo arroba e pelo ponto 
              if (ALetter = '@') then FoundAT := True
              else if (ALetter = '.') then FoundDOT := True;

              //se encontrou arroba e ponto então erscreve no memo2 o email
              if (FoundAT = True) and (FoundDOT = True) then
                Begin
                  AWord := '';
                  Memo2.Lines.Add('Email = ' + AEmail);
                End;
            End;
        End;
    End;
end;
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida avise.

Answer (score 0):

A seguinte rotina funcionaria em Python, você poderia tentar converter para usar a classe de expressões regulares do Delphi. Lembrando que não existe expressão regular que pegue 100% dos e-mails válidos, mas expressões boas pegam 99.9...%.

```
import re
import sys

email_regex = "[\w\.\+\-]+\@[\w]+\.[a-z]{2,3}"
regex = re.compile(email_regex)

data = open(sys.argv[1]).read()

for email in regex.finditer(data):
    print data[email.start(0):email.end(0)]
```